# socket.io not accessing the value in node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, real-time

I have the value to be updated in real-time using socket.io.The value is passed using event-emitter from backend to frontend and value is also passed and accessed in event-emitter but as in socket, I am passing the value, it is null and thus, not updated on frontend

```
const eventEmitter = req.app.get('eventEmitter');
eventEmitter.emit('getBookQty', foundBook.qty);  

eventEmitter.on('getBookQty',data =>{
    io.emit('getBook', data);
})


// app.js file
socket.on('getBook', (data) => {       // the program is not getting into this method.
    console.log("from app.js" , data);
    qty.innerHTML = data    
})
```

Comment: if you're using socket.io, it is supposed to be `io.emit()` instead of the built-in js `eventEmitter`

Comment: My project is created on MVC based architecture and on the controller file I need  to use socket but connection is setup in server.js file and I don't find a way to use it in another file

Comment: Got you. the event handler is called and the problem is just on the value?

Comment: yes, I am not getting value inside socket.io, else is working

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am able to understand first is EventEmmiter is on the backend side.

So, why do you have `getBookQty` as an emitting and listening event both on the backend side?

**Note: whenever the socket emits any event, by default it emits to all except itself.**

So as I'm understanding this in your case when frontend requests for `getBookQty` it will just execute

```
eventEmitter.on('getBookQty',data =>{
    io.emit('getBook', data);
})
```

So, here `data` variable will be null. It will emit null.

If I am wrong can you share more code separating front-end and back-end?

Comment: The event emitter emits the data from another controller file and it listens to the event on server.js file where the socket connection is set up. So the data listens from event emitter and it is emitted from socket.io to get the data on client side.

Comment: Can you share more code snippets of where you defined io, Socket, and entry point to understand so that I can trace it. Also, are you sure that the socket is connected on client-side?

Comment: here the code is

Comment: https://github.com/vasantisuthar/college-library-system, check out app/http/controllers/student/studentController.js where I have emitted the event through event emitter, initialization of event emitter is server.js file and client file is resources/js/app.js

Comment: Also, the socket is connected on the server as well as client side.

Comment: I have looked it up in code. Everything seems fine. But I am unable to run it due to a missing environment file. I have tried to reproduce your code here.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YbGiSRamQgHItXO5pE517KPWrmy62w-Yd6T1InSg0Sk/edit?usp=sharing   you can check it out. Also, if it is possible please share your complete code with the environment file so that I can debug it end to end.